# Twitter single-sign-on for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, twitter

The Facebook app has a really nice "single-sign-on" feature that uses URLs to send authentication requests to the Facebook app (where the user is normally already logged in).

Is there a similar functionality for Twitter? Most Twitter libraries I've evaluated uses a web browser, but they don't seem to keep the session, and the user has to enter the password every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone would still get here, this question is kind of obsoleted by the [Twitter framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html) now in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

There is no sign out from Twitter OAuth/xAuth...

you need to implement client side solution:

persistently store the access token in the NSUSerDefaults (it never expires unless the user revoke your application from account) when log in store the accesstoken, username ... etc and "keeping the user signed in", everytime when the app has accessToken...then it doesnt ask Login.

Therefore its ask u for login until he logs out from the Twitter.

when Logging out delete the Content stored using NSUserDefaults (in this case the access token)
hope that will help